# Tanstack vue-query reloading data when getting out of tab, and (possibly) not using cache

Tags: vue.js, vue-query

I am writing an app generator. I intend to use all of the best practices for everything. However, I have recently moved ro vue/tanstack and I am still working out what the best practices are -- this is especially hard with Vue, since everything has changed in the last year and a half.
Anyhow, this is a file generated by js-kit. I was hoping I could have some feedback in terms of having made huge mistakes.
I have some issues:

- Changing tabs, and re-focussing the tab, triggers a reload. This is especially bad since this is an editing screen -- imagine a user typing a long description, then popping onto a new tab to search something, go back to the editing screen, and BANG! everything is... gone!
- Cache. I am not sure the cache is being used. When I leave the editing screen (say, I save) and enter it again, it will reload. My understanding of the documentation is that it will provide data, and THEN triggers a reload, and only triggers a mutation if the data has changed. Well 1) I don't see this happening 2) If it DID happen in an editing screen, again, it would be kind of terrible (whereas in a viewing screen it would be  OK)

Ideas?

```
<script setup>
import { useDataLoader } from '@/lib/dataLoader.js'
import { ref, watch, computed } from 'vue'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { useQuery, useQueryClient, useMutation } from "@tanstack/vue-query"
import { cancelForm } from "@/lib/crudUtils.js"

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

const api = useDataLoader('projects')
let record = ref({})
const id = computed(() => { return route.params.id })

const { isLoading, isFetching, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['projects', id.value],
  queryFn: () => api.get(id.value).then(data => record.value = data),
})

// This is to make sure that data is reloaded if user navigates between sibling routes,
// where the route itself doesn't change, just params do
watch(() => id.value, () => { refetch() })

// Access QueryClient instance
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

const mutation = useMutation({
  mutationFn: (data) => api.put(id.value, data).then(data => record.value = data),
  onSuccess: (data) => {
    record.value = data
    queryClient.setQueryData(['projects', data.id ], data)
    router.push(`/projects`)  },
})

async function save (e) {
  const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target))
  await mutation.mutate(data)
}

</script>

<template>
    <layout-div>
        <h2 class="text-center mt-5 mb-3">Edit Projects</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <!--
                <router-link 
                    class="btn btn-outline-info float-right"
                    to="/projects">View All Projects
                </router-link>
                -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form @submit.prevent="save">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label :htmlFor="name">name</label>
                        <input 
                            :value="record.name"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="name"
                            name="name"/>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label :htmlFor="description">description</label>
                        <input 
                            :value="record.description"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="description"
                            name="description"/>
                    </div>

                    <button 
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3">
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button @click="cancelForm(router, `/projects`)"
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3">
                        Cancel
                    </button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </layout-div>
</template>


<style>
</style>
```